# Multiple Linear Layout not working

Tags: android, eclipse

Two `LinearLayout` `linearfirstRow` and `linearsecondRow` both has four buttons each.First linear layout works and second layout is not displayed.

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        linearfirstRow=new LinearLayout(this);
        linearfirstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearfirstRow.setId(1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams Layoutparam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,25);      
        linearfirstRow.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        setContentView(linearfirstRow);


        linearsecondRow=new LinearLayout(this);
        linearsecondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearsecondRow.setId(2);   
        linearsecondRow.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);


        btn_1=new Button(this);
        btn_1.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_2=new Button(this);
        btn_2.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_3=new Button(this);
        btn_3.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_4=new Button(this);
        btn_4.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);

        btn_5=new Button(this);
        btn_5.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_6=new Button(this);
        btn_6.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_7=new Button(this);
        btn_7.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);
        btn_8=new Button(this);
        btn_8.setLayoutParams(Layoutparam1);

        linearfirstRow.addView(btn_1);
        linearfirstRow.addView(btn_2);
        linearfirstRow.addView(btn_3);
        linearfirstRow.addView(btn_4);

buttons are -->     linearsecondRow.addView(btn_5);
notdisplayed        linearsecondRow.addView(btn_6);
                    linearsecondRow.addView(btn_7);
                    linearsecondRow.addView(btn_8);
```

Comment: Why don't you biuld the UI by XML?

Answer (score 1):

`linearfirstrow` is displaying because of this `setContentView(linearfirstRow);`

for the linearsecondRow to display add this at the last part of `onCreate()`

```
addView(linearsecondRow);
```